# Getting image size by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why did you select **an image twice** the size of the second order image is not showing?

My full code: http://jsfiddle.net/ayxZM/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleFiles(files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            alert(files[i].size + " Bytes");
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your field like this. I tested it. It works perfectly.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function handleFiles(files) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                    {
                       alert(files[i].size + ' Bytes' );
                       reset_field('handleFilesfield');
                }
                }

                function reset_field(id) {
                $('#'+id).html($('#'+id).html());
                }

            </script>
            ​<form>
                <span id="handleFilesfield"><input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"/></span>
            </form>
```

Comment: What if the value needs to be retained so that it can be submitted?

Comment: Well then just save it somewhere while inside handleFiles. You can even assign it to another form field in your page, so you can retain it. At least, your value will not be associated with your file input.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the *same* image twice then the image selection hasn't really changed, so the `onchange` handler isn't fired. If you select a *different* image its size is displayed.

Comment: I select the same image twice, What do i do?

Comment: Why do you need to do anything? You've already done something with that image's details the first time...

Answer (score 0):

Because when you click on the same image, the second time, there is no change of file, so the `onchange` event does not get triggered, so the function `handleFiles` does not get called, so the size does not get displayed. Use another event for this case. Maybe you could reset the input file inside the `handleFiles` function. That way, even if the user selects the same image again, it will be considered as a new image, and therefore the `onchange` event will get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here already: `onchange` does not fire when you select the same image (= don't change the value – see? that makes sense). But if you want to fire `onchange` everytime you can try reseting the value in `onmousedown` event. That way the value stays for submission and also forces `onchange` to fire. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LeZuse/ayxZM/27/
NOTE: If you need it to be touch compatible, you may wanna use `ontouchstart` also.